# toLocaleDateString is not a function in react jsx render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

Im trying to convert my date into a readable format, it current outputs as `2019-02-22T20:23:52.011Z`

I tried adding the .toLocaleDateString to format this date but I keep getting the same error of

`TypeError: item.CreateDate.S.toLocaleDateString is not a function`

Im unsure if this is because I'm doing this within the render? I then tried to declare this var before the return in the map arrow function however this didn't seem to make a difference. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  renderOrders() {
    return (
      <div class="sl-orders-container">
        {this.state.orders.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="order-item-row">
              <div className="">
                {JSON.parse(item.BasketData.S)[0].ProductName.split(" - ")[0]}
              </div>
              <div class="sl-orders-order">
                <div class="">Order Detail</div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    Date Purchased: {item.CreateDate.S.toLocaleDateString()}
                  </li>
```

Example Item

```
    BasketTotal: {S: "80"}
    CreateDate: {S: "2019-02-23T02:44:07.499Z"}
    EventTicketCount: {S: "2"}
    Paid: {BOOL: true}
```

Comment: Then `item.CreateDate.S` is not a date object - you likely want `new Date(item.CreateDate.S).toLocaleDateString()` but we would have known, had you posted an example of your item

Comment: what are the contents of item, and what's in the CreateDate function? Whatever you end up passing to toLocaleDateString() has to be a Date object

Comment: Please post what is `console.log( item.CreateDate )` and `console.log( typeof item.CreateDate )` in your main post. You can also post an image that would help also.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, I added   

`let purchasedDate = new Date(item.CreateDate.S).toLocaleDateString();`

just above the second return and it worked a dream :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

`{new Date(**your date**).toLocaleDateString()}`

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mplungjan the issue here was `item.CreateDate.S` was not a date object,

I then had to use

`Date Purchased: {new Date(item.CreateDate.S).toLocaleDateString()}`

instead of

`Date Purchased: {item.CreateDate.S.toLocaleDateString()}`